# Regex for any file not ends with

Tags: regular-expressions, find-file

How to write a function for finding all files in a directory which not ending with `pyc` and `pyo`?
I've tried something like `(find-lisp-find-files root "^(?!.*pyc$).*$")` but it does not return any possible result.

Comment: Note that for interactive use there is also the customizable variable `completion-ignored-extensions`. If you add `.pyc` and `.pyo` there files with those extensions are not offered for completion. Sometimes that is all one needs.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers to mark this question answered. Have you tried `list-files` from my answer? It should cover pretty everything what you could possibly need interactively as well as for coding. I test it occasionally since I wrote it and it seems to work well. Best regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `(?!.*pyc$)` is regular expression syntax of perl ([zero negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) that does [not work in emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html).

You can use

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(cl-remove-if
 (lambda (file) (or
                 (file-directory-p file)
                 (string-match "\\.py[co]$" file)))
 (directory-files default-directory))
```

It maybe that you have already the `(require 'cl-lib)` in your initialization. In that case you do not need it here.

There are many ways to modify the above code segment. For an example you can add a regular expression filter to `directory-files`. [See the help for `directory-files`.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Contents-of-Directories.html) You can also wrap this segment with a [`defun`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/defun.html) for easy use. You can also replace `directory-files` by `directory-files-recursively` if you want to recurse into sub-directories.

An example for a (sparsely tested) command `list-files` with optional regular expressions for filtering files in and out:

```el
(require 'cl-lib)
(require 'dired)

(defun dired-files-noselect (dir files)
  "Print files from list FILES in directory DIR using `dired-mode'."
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create (directory-file-name dir))
    (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
      (cd dir)
      (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
      (insert "  " default-directory (format ":\n  dired-files %d\n" (length files)))
      (dolist (file files)
        (let ((a (file-attributes file 'string)))
          (insert (format "  %s %d %s %s %6d %s %s\n"
                          (nth 8 a) ; file modes like ls -l
                          (nth 1 a) ; number of links to file
                          (nth 2 a) ; uid as string
                          (nth 3 a) ; gid as string
                          (or (nth 7 a) 0) ; size in bytes
                          (format-time-string "%d. %b %Y" (nth 5 a)) ; modification time
                          file))))
      (dired-mode)
      (dired-build-subdir-alist)
      (buffer-name))))

(defun dired-files (dir files)
  "Print files from list FILES in directory DIR using `dired-mode'."
  (display-buffer (dired-files-noselect dir files)))

(defconst list-files-options
  '((:directory default-directory "files of this directory are listed" read-directory-name "Directory: " nil nil t)
    (:recursively nil "recurse into sub-directories" y-or-n-p "Recurse into sub-directories (y/n)?: ")
    (:include ".*" "files to list must match this regular expression or fulfill this predicate" read-regexp "Include files matching: ")
    (:exclude nil "files that match this regular expression or fulfill this predicate are filtered out" read-regexp "Exclude files matching: ")
    (:include-directories nil "directories are included in the listing if this option is non-nil" y-or-n-p "Include sub-directories (y/n)?: "))
  "Alist of options for `list-files'.
Each option has the structure (key . (default-value doc-string)).")

(eval `(defun list-files (&rest options)
         ,(concat
           "List files.
Options (with default value in parentheses):
"
           (mapconcat (lambda (opt)
                        (concat (symbol-name (car opt))
                                " ("
                                (prin1-to-string (cadr opt))
                                ") "
                                (caddr opt)))
                      list-files-options
                      "\n")
           "

Example:
(list-files :exclude \"\\\\.py[co]$\")")
  (interactive
   (let (opt options)
     (while (null (string-equal
                   ""
                   (setq opt (completing-read "Option (try tab-completion): " (mapcar (lambda (opt) (substring (symbol-name (car opt)) 1)) list-files-options) nil t))))
       (setq opt (assoc-string (concat ":" opt) list-files-options))
       (setq options (append (list (car opt) (apply #'funcall (nthcdr 3 opt))) options)))
     options))
  (let* ((dir (plist-get options :directory))
         (dir (if dir dir default-directory))
         (include (plist-get options :include))
         (exclude (plist-get options :exclude))
         (full (plist-get options :full))
         (file-list (if (plist-get options :recursively)
                        (directory-files-recursively dir
                                                     (or (and (stringp include) include)  ".*")
                                                     (plist-get options :include-directories))
                      (directory-files dir t (and (stringp include) include))))
         (file-list (if (functionp include)
                        (cl-remove-if-not include file-list)
                      file-list))
         (file-list (if exclude
                        (cl-remove-if (if (functionp exclude)
                                          exclude
                                        `(lambda (file)
                                           (string-match ,exclude file)))
                                      file-list)
                      file-list))
         (file-list (if full 
                        file-list
                      (let ((default-directory dir))
                        (mapcar #'file-relative-name file-list)))))
    (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
      (dired-files dir file-list))
    file-list)))
```

Answer (score 5):

The way you intended this to be done:

```
(find-lisp-find-files "." "\\(^..?\\|py[^co]\\|[^p]..\\|.[^y].\\)$")
```

which, probably requires some explanation.

#### Why your attempt didn't work

Emacs doesn't have zero-width assertions in regular expressions. Also, you need to escape the parenthesis in Emacs regexp.

#### What does the regular expression match

It matches three characters at the end of the file name. There are three cases:

1. `py` followed by something that is neither `c` nor `o`.
2. `p` followed by something that is not `y`, followed by any character.
3. any character but `p` followed by `y` and then any other character.

thus ensuring anything that ends in either `pyc` or `pyo` will not match, but everything else will.

---

PS. You might want to check <kbd>M-x</kbd>`regexp-builder`.

Comment: Cool regexp! It assumes filename has at least 3 characters, it is almost right except for something like `/f`, though it's very very rare.

Comment: @xuchunyang oops, right, well, that can be fixed too :)

Comment: I though `\\(?:...\\)` was a [noncapturing group](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html#index-non_002dcapturing-group-3757).

Comment: @npostavs yes, it is. But in a different sense. The lookaround kind of groups don't capture in the sense they don't consume any input, and this one is noncapturing in the sense it doesn't create backreferences. I think the names for these things don't really reflect what they do...

Comment: `\(?:...\)` is *very definitely* a non-capturing (or "shy") group. What Emacs doesn't have is (certain kinds of) zero-width look-ahead/behind *assertions*.

Comment: @phils OK, I'll replace it with "assertions". But, as I wrote above: I don't like the choice of name for any of these.

Answer (score 4):

Elisp regular expressions are hard to read, hard to get right and even harder to maintain. Here are two alternative approaches:

**foreign-regexp.el** -- https://github.com/k-talo/foreign-regexp.el

Allows you to use regexps just like in perl, python, javascript or ruby. This is not a widely used or tested package but great if you really do not want to deal with elisp regexps.

**rx** -- built-in macro, see its documentation string and examples at http://francismurillo.github.io/2017-03-30-Exploring-Emacs-rx-Macro/

This macro takes a readable description of the matches needed and generates the regexp. Anyone can go and modify the description without getting lost in the forest of backlashes.

The following is a reworking of previous examples. Changing `unless` to `if` lists matching files.

```
(delq nil
  (mapcar
   (lambda (i)
     (unless (string-match-p
               (rx ".py" (any "c" "o") eos )
               i)
       i))
   (directory-files default-directory)))
```

Comment: Seems a bit pointless to add `(require 's)` just so you can write `s-matches-p` instead of `string-match-p`.

Comment: Correct and corrected. Blaming copy and paste and laziness.